# C# generic method can't create List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I have one Interface and two classes.

```
public interface IMyInterface { }
public class A : IMyInterface { }
public class B : IMyInterface { }
```

I have a generic method,

```
private List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable table) 
            where T : class, IMyInterface
{
    ...
}
```

which should return a object-list based on data in DataTable. So, I create a list in this method which I want to return at the end. I thought I could do the following,

```
private List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable table)
           where T : class, IMyInterface
{
   List<T> myList = new List<T>;

   // Now I thought I could easily add Objects based on T because,
   // both classes implement the interface

   if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
   {
      myList.Add(new B());
   }
   else
   {
      myList.Add(new A());
   }

   return myList;
}
```

But the compiler tells me that "Argument type A (B) is not assigneable"! Why is it not assignable?

---

Ok, alternatively can I do the following,

```
private List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable table)
           where T : class, IMyInterface
{
   List<IMyInterface> myList = new List<IMyInterface>;

   // Now I can assign the Object's :)
   if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
   {
      myList.Add(new B());
   }
   else
   {
     myList.Add(new A());
   }

   return myList as List<T>;
}
```

The compiler didn't complain but the result of the return clause is always null. For sure there are values in `myList`. The cast seems to fail. Someone please help me to solve this problem more elegantly.

Comment: you are looking for : `myList.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)));` or something around those line. Or cast as `(IMyInterface)` instead of `(T)`. It's confusing if you return Generic or not. Generic should be use when you don't know the type that might be used but here you seems to know the type is `IMyInterface`

Comment: @Franck there is an easier approach than using reflection, particularly if it's a parameterless constructor (see [new Constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable table) where T : class, IMyInterface {
   List<T> myList = new List<T>();
   if (typeof(T) == typeof(B)) {
      myList.Add((T)new B());
   }
   else {    
     myList.Add((T)new A());
   }
   return myList
}
```

Comment: @Sebi Null list? why?

Comment: Delete my comment. I have done something wrong. This works as expected :)

Answer (score 5):

One way is to add `new()` constraint. Limitation is that you need a public parameterless constructor for the type argument T.

```
private static List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable table) where T : class, IMyInterface, new()
{
    List<T> myList = new List<T>();
    T instance = new T();
    //access anything defined in `IMyInterface` here
    myList.Add(instance);
    return myList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Why do you even need generics?

You were going the right way initially, deriving your types from the same interface, so make use of it. Declare your list `List<IMyInterface>` and simply add your objects as they are.

If later you actually need a physical representation of an enumerable with concrete `A` or `B` types, you have `OfType<>()` and `Cast<>()` for it, though it shows your polymorphism was done wrong in the first place.

Comment: i thought it would be great if the user of my class can name the type he want to get. He want a list with A so he directly get a List<A> otherwise List<B>. But maybe it is easier to return List<IMyInterface> :\

Comment: Again, that's what `OfType<>()` is for.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`new` constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

```
private List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable table) where T : class, IMyInterface, new()
{
   return new List<T>(){ new T() };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast object, before add it to List:

```
 private static List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable table) where T : class, MyInterface
    {
        List<T> myList = new List<T>();

        //Now i thought i can easily add Objects based on T, because both classes
        //implement the interface
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (B))
        {
            // use of 'as' operator
            myList.Add(new B() as T);
        }
        else
        {
            myList.Add(new A() as T);
        }

        return myList;
    }
```

But anyway I am not getting a point, what your are trying to achieve.

Also `myList as List<T>` will surely result as `null`, since you cannot cast generic collection with `as` operator as `List<T>` is not declared as [Covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx). You should explicitly call `.Cast<T>()` method to create new collection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you actually want to do something like,

```
public IList<T> GetList<T>(
        DataTable table,
        Func<DataRow, T> extractor)
{
    var result = new T[table.Rows.Count];
    for (var i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        result[i] = extractor(table.Rows[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

`extractor` being the delegate for converting a `DataRow` to `T`.

---

this would work more simply than you might expect,

```
// referencing System.Data.DataSetExtensions

var list = GetList(
        data,
        row => new A
            {
                Id = row.Field<int>("id"),
                ...
            });
```

`list` would be an `IList<A>` among other types.

Answer (score 0):

Right only for class A and B

```
 static List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable table) where T : class, IMyInterface
        {
            List<T> myList = new List<T>();

            IMyInterface obj;
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
            {
                obj = new B();
            }
            else
            {
                obj = new A();
            }

            myList.Add((T)obj);

            return myList;
        }
```